# How to create a regular expression for this case?

Tags: regex

I have multiple file names in the following format:

```
Pipedream integration and automation.mp4_snapshot_00.00.981.jpg
It's been a long time, it's time to put it to sleep.mp4_snapshot_00.01.222.jpg
Mr. President, we are under attack.mp4_snapshot_00.20.151.jpg
```

What would be a regular expression that will get rid of the ending "mp4_snapshot_00.00.981" or similar for all files, leaving just file names as

```
Pipedream integration and automation.jpg
It's been a long time, it's time to put it to sleep.jpg
Mr. President, we are under attack.jpg
```

Thanks.

And the prize goes to... MrIrrelevant !! Thanks, man.

[image]

Comment: Replace `mp4_snapshot_\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\.` with `''`? https://regex101.com/r/S67UgT/1

Comment: The title is not especially informative but I have nothing to offer as a replacement.

Comment: please define "or similar". Is `wmv_snapshot_00.00.981` similar? `mp4_photo_00.00.981`? `mp4.snapshot_00_00_981` ? Specifying the rules for what is to be matched will give you your regular expression

Comment: Do you want to rename actual files (if so specify OS) or make changes to text (if so specify language/tool - regex does nothing to text; you need a language/tool to use regex to change it)

Comment: this is a very ugly solution, but worked in testing...
str.replace(/\.mp4_snapshot_[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+/, '')
that's javascript, or node if you're changing actual file file names...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming all non-desired parts start with mp4 and end before .jpeg this should work:

```
 (.mp4.*).jpg
```

Comment: And the prize goes to... MrIrrelevant !! Thanks, man.
Screenshot added to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Find:

```
^(.*\.)[^.]+_snapshot_[\d.]+\.([^.]+)$
```

Replace:

```
$1$2
```

Should handle all possible file extensions and timestamps

Comment: Almost! This did the trick: ^(.*\.)[^.]+_snapshot_[\d.]+[\d.]$